sistema de calculo varios campos y con decimales
nuevamente abro este caso el cual en el anterior post no se que pasó no pude solucionar bien pues no me supe explicar bien en la pregunta.
el caso es el siguiente tengo este sistema el cual adiciona celdas en el cual al ir agregando valores (V. Unitario) y la cantidad esta se va sumando (V.Total) y debajo se va haciendo un gran total (Total), acá en Colombia los precios se dividen en 3 decimales es decir 3.000, 40.000, etc.
el sistema funciona bien si a esto no se le pone puntos (decimales) pero yo le he puesto que en el campo valor unitario se vaya agregando el separador de decimales y es allí donde empieza mi problema,

No hace la suma bien,
No calcula el gran total bien quita los ceros.. tanto en V. Total como en Total
Y al agregar una cifra mayor (7 digitos) se desaparece el valor del campo V. unitario

Ayuda por favor...
      <form name="form1" method="post" action="enviacostos.php">
        <input name="id_servicio" type="hidden" id="id_servicio" value="<?php echo $id_servicio ?>" size="40">
        <input name="numero_servicio" type="hidden" id="numero_servicio" value="<?php echo $numero_servicio ?>" size="40">
        <input name="conducct" type="hidden" id="conducct" value="<?php echo $conductorgrua ?>" size="40">
        <div class="container" style="padding-left:25px">
          <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
                <thead>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td height="22">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>Producto</td>
                    <td>Cantidad</td>
                    <td>V. Unitario</td>
                    <td>V. Total</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr id='addr0'>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name='product[]'  placeholder='' list='brow' class="form-control" />
                      <datalist id='brow'>                
                        <option value='ACPM'>                        
                        <option value='COMIDA'>                        
                        <option value='HOTEL'>                        
                        <option value='OTROS'>                        
                      </datalist></td>
                    <td><input name='qty[]' type="number" class="form-control qty" placeholder='' min="0" step="0" value="1"/></td>
                    <td>
                    <!----<input type="number" name='price[]' placeholder='' class="form-control price" step="0" min="0" onKeyUp="format(this)" onChange="format(this)"/>--->
                   <input type="number" name='price[]' placeholder='' class="form-control price" onKeyUp="format(this)" onChange="format(this)"/>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="number" name='total[]' placeholder='' class="form-control total" readonly/></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr id='addr1'></tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-left:19px; padding-top:10px;">
              <button type="button" id="add_row" class="btn btn-default pull-left" >+ Producto</button>
              <button type="button" id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-default">- Producto</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row clearfix" style="margin-top:20px">
            <div class="pull-right col-md-4">
              <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic_total">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <th class="text-center">Total</th>
                    <td class="text-center"><input type="number" name='sub_total' placeholder='' class="form-control" id="sub_total" readonly/></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="15" bgcolor="#F0F1F2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="15" bgcolor="#999999">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js" integrity="sha256-eKhayi8LEQwp4NKxN+CfCh+3qOVUtJn3QNZ0TciWLP4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
function format(input)
{
var num = input.value.replace(/\./g,'');
if(!isNaN(num)){
num = num.toString().split('').reverse().join('').replace(/(?=\d*\.?)(\d{3})/g,'$1.');
num = num.split('').reverse().join('').replace(/^[\.]/,'');
input.value = num;
}
else{ alert('Solo se permiten numeros');
input.value = input.value.replace(/[^\d\.]*/g,'');
}
}
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 1;
  
  // Add
  $("#add_row").click(function() {
    b = i - 1;
    $('#addr' + i).html($('#addr' + b).html()).find('td:first-child').html(i + 1);
    $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr' + (i + 1) + '"></tr>');
    i++;
  });
  
  // Delete
  $("#delete_row").click(function() {
    if (i > 1) {
      $("#addr" + (i - 1)).html('');
      i--;
    }
    calc_total();
  });

  // On input value change
  $('#tab_logic tbody').on('input', 'input[type="number"]', function(evt) {
    calc($(evt.currentTarget).closest('tr'));
  });
  
  $('#tax').on('input', function() {
    calc_total();
  });


});

// Calcular total de la fila
function calc($tr) {
  var qty = $tr.find('.qty').val();
  var price = $tr.find('.price').val();
      
  // Total con 3 decimales
  $tr.find('.total').val((qty * price).toFixed(0));

  calc_total();
}

function calc_total() {
  var total = 0;
  $('#tab_logic .total').each(function() {
    // Obtener el valor como float
    total += parseFloat($(this).val());
  });
  // Dar formato con 3 decimales
  $('#sub_total').val(total.toFixed(0));
  
  // Esto podría estar en otra función
  tax_sum = total / 100 * $('#tax').val();
  $('#tax_amount').val(tax_sum.toFixed(0));
  $('#total_amount').val((tax_sum + total).toFixed(0));
}
</script>


Dicho: "nuevamente abro este caso el cual en el anterior post no se que pasó no pude solucionar bien pues no me supe explicar bien en la pregunta." Yo pregunto: por qué no editas la otra pregunta en lugar de crear una nueva?

Hola mateo gracias por responder, ya lo hice Mateo pero fueron tantos hilos de conversación que que abrieron que no sabría por donde empezar... por eso quedaba mejor hacer acá otro post con las mejoras

Cual es la diferencia entre esta pregunta y esta otra https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/624885/301324 ??

Hola Yussef gracias por responder, pues si notas hace lo mismo pero se abrieron respuestas que me enredaron un poquito y no pude a partir de allí.. no me juzguen mi nivel de JavaScript es pésimo y solo se lo básico... y en vista que se abrieron otros hilos no sabia que al editar alla se podia..

El formato del sitio es de preguntas y respuestas, no de hilos. Dicho esto, entonces: ¿cuál es específicamente la diferencia entre esta y aquella pregunta? Si aquella aún no se respondió, es simplemente editarla (siempre y cuando no cambie radicalmente el sentido de la misma).

Hola padaleiana gracias pro responder, en verdad lo siento, no sabia si después de tanto tiempo se podía revivir un post o editarlo. Saludos!!

@Eduardo Yo respondí la anterior, entiendo que pude haber sido poco claro. El tema es que debes especificar que no entiendes (en los comentarios de esa respuesta). De lo contrario yo puedo volver a responder esta misma, con la misma otra respuesta y entramos en un loop infinito

ok Yussef mil gracias!!.. no se porque me compliqué tanto!! en ultimas decidimos quitarle el campo de descuento para que no se nos complicara mucho!!!

Creo que debes diferenciar entre mostrar el separador de miles  y utilizarlo. Lo que necesitas es que se muestre correctamente, pero debes eliminarlo antes de realizar tus cálculos.
